# Intermittent / random disconnection from Firebase - everything stops working

Tags: firebase

I've search high and low for an answer, damn near going through every possible Firebase question on Stackoverflow. So here we go.

I have a webapp and cordova app that uses Firebase throughout. Everything works flawlessly, except occasionally the apps lose connection (usually after being in the background for a while) and everything stops working. No offline mode, no loading additional data, even Firebase.goOnline() doesn't kick it back in to gear. The only thing I can do is refresh the entire app and all is right in the world again.

But I can not for the life of me reproduce this on my own - it seems completely random.

Can anyone thing of any possible cause of this - or at least point me in a direction that I can keep trying to actively reproduce this?

Comment: I would recommend trying two things - (1) enable Firebase logging via `Firebase.enableLogging(true)` to capture a log of the internal activity, and (2) once you've got a log of the event, or a test case / steps that reproduce the issue, reach out the Firebase folks at support@firebase.com